# Why $p^2$ is strictly contained in q?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A =K[x,y], K is a field, q=(x,$y^2$), p=(x,y). Then why $p^2$ is strictly contained in q? I think xy is in $p^2$, but I do not see why it is also in q? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: $p^2=(x^2, xy, y^2)$, $q\not\subset p^2$.

Comment: I have edited the title. Then why xy is in q?

Comment: It is in q. See the answer below. And thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p^2=(x^2,xy,y^2)$.

$x^2 = x\cdot x + y^2\cdot 0 \in q$.

$xy = x\cdot y + y^2\cdot 0\in q$.

$y^2 = x\cdot 0 + y^2\cdot 1 \in q$.

So, $p^2 \subseteq q$.

Now, $x$ is in $q$ but not in $p^2$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!